# jekyll minimal mistakes - "feature_row" alignment of image top and button bottom

Tags: css, jekyll

theme: minimal mistakes

[image]

What I dont like in the image is that the buttons of the columns are not aligned

i use feature_row for showing posts on start page. I want

- the preview images aligned top
- the subtitles of the columns aligned with each other
- the excerpt of the columns aligned with each other
- the buttons aligned with each other
- and it should still be responsive

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS issue. You will need to modify the CSS.

The `display:grid` layout can do what you want. Other layouts could also work. [Here](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/) is the CSS grid bible. You might like [this example](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example16/)